# Updating single item in react state hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-map-gl

I have array useState hook which consists of items with className. I want to update  className of a single item from that hook. How do I update single value of a useState hook.Of course I am going to put condition before updating .
here is the code -

```
 display.map( word => 
   ( Words[leftPointer] === word.props.children ? 
      {...display, word:(<span key={uuid()} className="singleWord greenword"> 
      {Words[leftPointer]}</span>)} :
        display )
        )
 setDisplay(display)
```

here display contains array of span.
what I want is go change the className based on the condition example- after updating the item
className = "singleWord greenword" should be className="singleWord" of that item.

Comment: So `display` is an array of "span" and you want to change the `className` of only one "span" ? What is the condition to identify that specific "span" ?

Comment: I am comparing my input word with the word inside span(I did it) the problem is I don't know how to update single item of a state my code does not do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map function will return a new array so you just have to store the array in a new variable and set the state with that new variable

```
const newDisplay = display.map( (word) =>{ 
    if(Words[leftPointer] === word.props.children){
      return {word:(<span key={uuid()} className="singleWord greenword"> 
      {Words[leftPointer]}</span>)}
    }else{
        return word
    }
  })
  setDisplay(newDisplay)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against setting `className` in the state's domain as that is part of the UI's domain. Instead data changes can be used to signal responses in the UI rendering. This is what it means for a program to be [data-driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_programming).

Here is a minimal verifiable example. <kbd>Run</kbd> the program below and change some quantities to see the `display` state update. The `className` is automatically changed based on conditions applied to the application state.

```js
function App() {
  const [display, setDisplay] = React.useState([
    {item: "walnut", quantity: 0 },
    {item: "peanut", quantity: 3 },
    {item: "donut", quantity: 6 }
  ])
  function update(index) { return event =>
    setDisplay([
      ...display.slice(0, index),
      { ...display[index], quantity: Number(event.target.value) },
      ...display.slice(index + 1)
    ])
  }   
  return <div>
    {display.map((d, index) =>
      <div key={index}>
        {d.item}:
        <input
          className={d.quantity > 0 ? "instock" : "outofstock" }
          value={d.quantity}
          onChange={update(index)}
        />
      </div>
    )}
    <div>{display.every(d => d.quantity > 0) ? "✅" : "❌"}</div>
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(display, null, 2)}</pre>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
input { outline: 0 }
.instock { border-color: limegreen; }
.outofstock { border-color: red; }
pre { padding: 0.5rem; background-color: #ffc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I will try your solution

Answer (score 0):

could you just use a state variable that holds the text for `className` and update that state variable on the useState hook to whatever you want?

Comment: it would be helpful if you kindly give a demo.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).